# How to make right click menu in Flash with "open in new window" for sIFR link?

Tags: flash, sifr

How to make right click menu in Flash with "open in new window" for sIFR link?

Can we make in sIFR3 directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, you need to worry about that as sIFR automatically does that for you. Here is an [example](http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/beta2/demo/). It gives two options in Right-Click context menu. (1: Follow the link, 2: Open link in new Window).

Comment: is it available in sIFR 2 or only for sIFR 3?

Comment: I am no sure about sIFR2. The best way is 'give it a try'. :)

Comment: sIFR 3, if you are replacing exactly a link, and there is nothing else in the Flash movie.

Comment: so this option is not available in sifr2